# Awk doesn't exit despite "exit 0" command

Tags: awk, pipe, docker, coreutils

I have the following command:

```
sudo docker logs -f <id> | awk '/Listening on / {print $3; exit 0;}'
```

From what I understand, awk should find the first line that matches the pattern, print the correct column, and exit. However, this does not always happen: most the time it simply prints the correct column and hangs, although occasionally it exits correctly.

I've tried

```
$ sudo stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 docker logs ...  # hangs
$ sudo docker logs ... | cat | awk ... # hangs
```

In trying to produce a minimal example, I also tried making a pipe using `mkfifo`, and using `cat foo | awk ...` but that doesn't hang.

The output from `docker logs -f <id>` is

```
Listening on 172.17.0.2/16
...
```

and then it remains open, but doesn't write any thing else.

I don't understand what's going on--does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Unable to replicate:  `for i in {10..20}; do echo $i; done | awk '{ exit 0} END { print NR}'` works as apparently intended.

Comment: Similar: [How to print only one match of grep when tail -f?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/300115) or [Grep slow to exit after finding match?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/366797) or [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/416150). Most likely `awk` exits but your shell is waiting for all processes in the pipeline.

Comment: Your output above indicates docker logs is emitting terminal sequences; are you certain that it isn’t when you pipe it to awk?   Maybe pipe it into hexdump just to have a peek.

Comment: @mevets I assume you're referring to the syntax highlighting? StackExchange is doing that, the output is plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before
>   returning a value.

I don't have docker installed but maybe try this:

```
awk '/Listening on / {print $3; exit 0;}' <( sudo docker logs -f <id> )
```

Or you could try this:

```
sudo docker logs -f <id> | (awk '/Listening on / {print $3; exit 0;}'; pkill -P $$ )
```

So perhaps an explanation of what is going on would help. I'm assuming that the 'docker logs' command does not normally exit (the -f == follow?).

The original problem arises because the pipeline is not exiting on awk's termination - this is because the pipeline is still waiting on the docker program (see my extract above from the bash man page).

The pkill simply kills anything that has parent id $$ - ie at that moment, that is just docker.

Obviously, it would not be a good idea to chuck that command into background with '&' and then run other things - they would also get killed!

Comment: Yup, this is exactly it! This behavior is surprising, although not unexpected--the only way it could work otherwise is if bash sent SIGINT or SIGQUIT to the other programs in the pipe, and I've never seen that happen. Thank you!